# What is the purpose of fetching changes before merging in git?

Tags: git

I read that before merging you should fetch the changes for the branch you're about to merge, switch to master and pull any changes there, and then merge. What's the point of fetching changes for the branch you're about to merge? Why wouldn't you push it instead?

Comment: Is this a branch which others are working on?

Comment: I haven't ever worked on a branch that wasn't my own or that was shared by others. But in this scenario let's say it is shared by others.

Comment: Then yes, you'd need to fetch their work and merge yours in very similar to in my answer. I actually recommend a fetch and *rebase* to rewrite your work on top of theirs and keep the branch simple, `git pull --rebase`. But rebasing requires a solid understanding of Git.

Answer (score 2):

Because you want to be sure you're merging with the latest code.

Git is *decentralized* meaning everyone has their own copy of the repository. These copies must be coordinated and kept up to date by fetching, pushing, and pulling (which is just a fetch and a merge). Git does not do this for you, you must do it manually.

Let's say you're going to merge your feature branch into master. Your repository looks like this.

```
A - B [master]
     \
      C - D [feature]
```

You merge without first updating.

```
$ git checkout master
$ git merge feature

A - B ----- M [master]
     \     /
      C - D [feature]
```

And then try to push... but its rejected! Someone else has changed master since you last fetched.

```
origin

      E - F
     /     \
A - B ---- N [master]

local
A - B ----- M [master]
     \     /
      C - D [feature]
```

You could pull, and Git will merge your work with theirs, but the result is a bit of a mess.

```
$ git pull

       E - F
      /     \
     / ----- N [origin/master]
    |/        \
A - B ----- M - O [master]
     \     /
      C - D [feature]
```

The result is new code which has to be retested.

---

If you instead had updated master first...

```
$ git checkout master
$ git pull

      E - F
     /     \ [origin/master]
A - B ---- N [master]
     \
      C - D [feature]
```

Now you can merge, test, and push. The result is a simpler history.

```
$ git merge feature
$ git push

      E - F
     /     \     [origin/master] 
A - B ---- N -- O [master]
     \         /
      C ----- D [feature]
```

Comment: I understand the need to update master, but I read that you also need to do git fetch for the branch (in this case feature) and I don't understand why.

Comment: @user13985180 Same reason. If someone else has pushed changes to the branch you need to merge with (or rebase onto) them before you can push. Otherwise the branch has "diverged". `git push` will not merge for you. If you never pushed the branch, you're fine.

Answer (score 0):

Most time you need to fetch the code written by other people when you collaborate with others.
The `fetch` will give you a chance to review the code of others, and decide to merge it or not.
`git pull` is not recommended, always fetch first, review the code, then consider to use `rebase` first.
[Why You Should Use git pull –ff-only](https://blog.sffc.xyz/post/185195398930/why-you-should-use-git-pull-ff-only)

Comment: Pull is fine unless you really don't trust the other collaborators. Remember, everything can be undone. But manually doing a fetch and merge is educational and safe until one learns how to undo a bad merge.